# the composite function $G(z) = g(2z−2+i)$ is analytic in the half plane $x>1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, partial-derivative

The following problem is from Brown Churchil's Complex Analysis book.

The function $g(z)=√re^{iθ/2} (r > 0,−π < θ < π) $ is analytic in its domain of deﬁnition, with derivative $g(z) = \frac{1}{ 2g(z)}$ . Show that the composite function $G(z) = g(2z−2+i)$ is analytic in the half plane $x>1$, with derivative $G'(z) = \frac{1}{ g(2z−2+i)}$ .

Suggestion: Observe that $Re(2z−2+i) > 0$ when  $x>1$.

I can not understand the suggestion. I think the composite function $G(z) = g(2z−2+i)$ is analytic in $ x> 1$ and $y= -1/2$. Because the negative axis has been excluded from the domain of $g(z)$.

Can anyone please help me to mention what I am getting wrong?

Comment: I am also doing complex analysis from brown and churchill but this problem has me perplexed. Can you tell me whether they want us to just show that the function is analytic in the region defined in the problem itself...or does it want us to show the function is analytic only in the region defined in the problem?. Because I think the function in the region $\{(x,y):x\leq 1\, \text{and}\,y\neq \frac{1}{2}\}$ is also analytic

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron  I also think last line true

Answer (score 2):

Well first, the function is *not* analytic on $y = -\frac{1}{2}$. You solved for Im$(2z-2+i) = 0$, which tells you where the original function was not defined, thus you should conclude that $f$ is analytic on $x > 1$ and $y \not = -\frac{1}{2}$. 
However, for a point $z$ to be on the negative real axis for the composite function, it needs to satisfy *both* requirements, Re$(2z-2+i) \leq 0$ and Im$(2z-2+i) = 0$. Thus after restricting to the right half plane, there are no points which hit the imaginary real axis under the map $z\rightarrow (2z-2+i)$. 
So in general, you need to "intersect" your two constraints Re$(z) > 0$ and Im($z) \not = 0$, to find the domain of analyticity. In this case, we are intersecting the horizontal line $y = -\frac{1}{2}$ and the region $x > 1$, which is of course, just the region $x > 1$. Then the fact that the derivative is what they claim it is follows from a straightforward application of the chain rule.

Comment: I am also doing complex analysis from brown and churchill but this problem has me perplexed. Can you tell me whether they want us to just show that the function is analytic in the region defined in the problem itself...or does it want us to show the function is analytic only in the region defined in the problem?. Because I think the function in the region $\{(x,y):x\leq 1\, \text{and}\,y\neq \frac{1}{2}\}$ is also analytic